# SSL Handshake error with an Axis2 client on IBM JDK 6, SR 5

Tags: sslexception

An Axis2 Client invokes a 2 way mutual SSL secured mainframe based webservice.
The client is running on IBM JDK6, SR 5

```
            `
            Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
                   at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
                   at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:188)
                   at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:197)
                   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
                   ... 18 more
            Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.i(sc.java:401)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.j(sc.java:371)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.write(j.java:23)
                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
                   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:134)
                   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
                   ... 23 more
            Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:13)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:154)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:515)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:522)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:146)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.write(j.java:10)
                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
                   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:134)
                   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
                   at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
                   at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.flush(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:50)
                   at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:198)
                   at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:195)
                   ... 19 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.fb.<init>(fb.java:32)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:262)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:209)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.n(gb.java:140)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:123)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:320)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.g(sc.java:198)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:599)
                   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.write(j.java:20)
                   ... 29 more'
```

The application is hosted on WAS 7, fix pack 11

I tried going through the IBM forums for the fixes as part of SR 8 and I could locate this which is kind of close to my issue 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM35288

Comment: By the time I had posted this question, it got fixed in parallel.
So, this got fixed when I updated to IBM JDK SR 8.

Hope this helps others too.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it, so you can share your knowledge! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted shows that this issue was fixed in WAS 7 Fix Pack 19 and above.

Comment: Yep, upgrading the fixpack was out of question for the production environment and hence I just ignored it. the JDK upgrade however resolved it. thanks